# how to specify a service rather than a product with checkout express

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have started using checkout express integration with my website and the first payment receipt indicates a product rather a service. It referres to shipping if not already shipped.

How can I customise the transaction so paypal knows this is a service and so no items need delivery and the 7 day refund does not apply as a service cannot be refunded that has started.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a variable to control the type of product you're selling. You can, however, define the item details through the SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment call and label them clearly as a product.